# Can I create an "exception" to an IIS Virtual Directory?

Tags: iis, virtualdirectories

I have a folder on my server like this one:

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\blah

In IIS, I also have a "/blah" virtual folder set up, pointing to C:\BLAH

Naturally, when site visitors type in http://www.myserver.com/blah/test.html, IIS looks for C:\BLAH\test.html, not C:\inetpub\wwwroot\blah\test.html. For the most part, this is the behavior I want, because most of the files are in C:\BLAH. However, when the file DOES exist in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\blah, I'd like the server to look for it there first, and then look in C:\BLAH if it doesn't find it. Basically I'd like the files in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\blah to be an "exception" to the virtual directory. Have the server return the files from that folder, if they exist, but if they don't pull them from C:\BLAH instead of returning a 404.

I am running IIS 5.0 on Windows Server 2000.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: Which version of IIS?

Comment: It's Windows 2000 Server, so... IIS 5.0, I'd imagine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of ghetto, but it might be a simple way to solve your problem.

- Create a second virtual directory that points to c:\blah.
- In the "blah" virtual directory (which points to C:\inetpub\wwwroot\blah), setup a custom error handler for 404 errors that is an ASP or ASP.Net page in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\blah\
- In the 404 handler ASP.Net page,

  - pull the requested URL (it should be the only thing in Request.QueryString)
  - chop off everything but the filename requested
  - redirect to "/cblah/FILENAME".

Here is a little snippet of ASP.Net code that could act as the 404 handler:

```
string qs = Page.Request.QueryString.ToString();
qs = Server.UrlDecode(qs);
int c = qs.LastIndexOf("/");
string filepath = qs.Substring(c+1);
Response.Redirect("/cblah/"+filepath);
```

Comment: Brilliant! I'm sure that would work.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do this through a custom written ISAPI filter, but I am not aware of any way within IIS or an existing product that would do exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com) is a free URL Rewriter which has a capability to check for the existence of a directory, before rewriting.  The rules would look like:

```
# This rule matches, eg, http://server/blah/test.html
# It does "no rewrite" (-) if the file c:\blah\test.html does NOT exist. 
# The url stub /blah must map to an existing vdir. 
RewriteCond  c:\blah\$1        !-f
RewriteRule  ^/blah/(.*)$      -  [L]

# If the file does exist, rewrite to the alternative vdir. 
RewriteCond  c:\blah\$1           -f
RewriteRule  ^/blah/(.*)$         /override-vdir/$2    [L]
```

You can also wildcard "blah".  To do that you'd need a convention for naming the override vdirs.  It would look something like this:

```
# This rule matches, eg, http://server/blah/test.html
# It does nothing if the file c:\blah\test.html does not exist. 
RewriteCond  c:\$1\$2           !-f
RewriteRule  ^/([^/]+)/(.*)$    -  [L]

RewriteCond  c:\$1\$2            -f
RewriteRule  ^/([^/]+)/(.*)$    /override-$1/$2    [L]
```

There are also conditions for testing the existence of a directory.  Check [the IIRF doc](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/IirfHelp) for details.